# Connecting to localhost phpMyAdmin with android

Tags: php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi i have a local host phpMyAdmin and php code. On the local host i have a Database called android_api and table called users. In my JSONParser i have this code . Im using wamp, inside the wamp map i have one more map called WWW, in there i have a map with all php code called android_login

In my class that is called UserFunction i have this code

```
private static String loginURL = WHAT DO I PUT IN HERE?
private static String registerURL = AND HERE?
```

somebody help please

Comment: phpmyadmin is a website used to manage a mysql database. why do you need to programatically log into it? just fire up a webbrowser.

Comment: I answered Try and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your local host from your android emulator Use the ip address given in ipconfig.

Open command prompt->type ipconfig-> Get IPV4 address.... something like 192.xx...

[image]

So your URL="http://192.xx.xx.xx/loginAPI/file.php"

Comment: is this right ---- "http://192.xx.xx.xx/android_login.php  the map where all php files are located are called android_login and the database is called android_api and the tabel is called users

Comment: You get your system's IPV4 address. It must work

Comment: I am using it. you followed androidhive.info tutorial. Right?

Comment: http://youripaddress/foldername/filename.php

Comment: yes yes indra, i get a exeption that sad nullpointerexeption on this line of code ---try {
                     HERE IS THE EXEPTION-----   if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null).. this code is located in UserFunction

Comment: so i think its something wrong whit my url, what do you think.

Comment: Are you able to connect with local host?

Comment: if you want to test the connection with local host.... Just create a test.php file in android_api folder. And put this code in it. <?php echo "Local host tested"; ?> . Then open emulator's browser Visit 192.xx.xx.xx/android_api/test.php

Comment: i downloade the example on androhive, created the php files and a database on localhost/myphpadmin. when i start the program on android the exeption "nullponterExeption" comes up. the json string is empty. i used this url --"http://10.0.2.2/android_login/";

Comment: Get your IPV4 address and replace 10.0.2.2

Comment: IPv4 should be there

Comment: @Aleksander Are you able to connect or not ? Whats your ipv4 address and how do you access a test.php file which is placed in a folder called android_api from your computer's browser

Comment: cant connect :( The requested URL /android_api/test.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Ensure you created a test.php in android_api folder. If You are not able to access this file from your computer's browser, then your local host is not set up properly

Comment: thack you so much for the help im goign to try so solve it. But one more question loginURL = "http://192.168.0.125/android_api/file.php" which file do i put in, i have this files --- config.php index.php Db_functions.php and db_conect.php

Comment: file.php means the file you want to access. like login.php or register.php

Comment: If It has helped accept the answer